# Mount Blackburn Cargo Cage on Rockshox front suspension fork

Tags: mountain-bike, bikepacking

Im trying to find a way to attach one [Blackburn Outpost Cargo cage](https://www.blackburndesign.com/p/outpost-cargo-bike-cage/350130000100000010.html) to each side of my rockshox front suspension. Are there any good way to mount them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can buy clamps specifically for this from most decent bike shops, especially those that stock bike packing and touring gear. A homebrew solution of hose clamps is quite commonly used. Some have used heavy Zip ties successfully, but I would be concerned about the strength (Great for emergency trail side repair though) and getting the bracket tight enough on the fork not to move around.

It is worth protecting the fork with something like Duct tape, or better, a piece of old tube. This will also offer some grip to help stop the bracket moving around. It the bracket sliding down the fork or rotating is a problem, rather than clamp things tighter, you might be better to use a double sided tape with the hose clamps.

Comment: Even with an old tube, zip ties alone aren't great on rough ground (sliding down) or if there's a lot of vegetation along the trail (getting knocked into spokes). I've only used that approach above front panniers, otherwise I've used the upper rack screw and one cable tie. Hose clamps should be good though - again protect the frame against chafing and rust, or ideally track down stainless hose clamps